# Question about the method of characteristic coordinates to solve the wave equation

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, chain-rule, wave-equation

I'm working on learning how to solve the 1-D wave equation using characteristic coordinates and I am getting stumped by one of the steps.  Here is the part I am stuck on:

The textbook says that if $δ=x+ct$ and $φ=x-ct$ then $∂_x=∂_δ+∂_φ$  and $∂_t=c∂_δ-c∂_φ$.

I don't understand how the differentiation works here. Can someone explain the rules for how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the chain rule:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial\delta}
\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\varphi}
\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial\delta}
+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\varphi} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial\delta}
\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\varphi}
\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t}=c\frac{\partial f}{\partial\delta}
-c\frac{\partial f}{\partial\varphi}
\end{align*}

Comment: Ah, I see it now.  That was simpler than I thought.  Thanks for your answer!